# Theater database schema

Tags: database-schema

I have to implement a ticket selling service using php, where the user inputs the number of seats he/she wants, the system checks for availability and then presents random seats, the user confirms and the reservation is done.

First thing I have to do, is conclude to the database schema I will use. I am a little bit confused, so I will present you what I have thought so far. I really need your advice, in order to continue with the implementation.

I have concluded to the following tables:

- `Customer`: `id, name`
- `Ticket` : `ticket_id, time, price, seat_id`
- `Booking`: `id, customer_id, ticket_id`
- `Seat`: `id, status`

Τhe point is I am not sure about this, and pretty sure that it is false. For example the theater has a capacity (standard number of seats). So, where should I store this? Should I have a table `Theater: id, name, capacity` and when the admin completes for example the `capacity = 60`, then automatically I should make a query that inserts 60 records to the `Seats` table with `status=1` (available)?

I am confused. I will have to think about it more carefully, but a second opinion, would be really very helpful for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have to add something else. Something with ticket and booking tables , doesn't make sense to me. Some tickets that have been booked from the same person, will have the same booking id, right? But they will be seperate tickets. So, as I see my schema, something goes wrong. Maybe table ticket should have a reference to table booking, meaning have a field booking_id to the ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in thinking your current schema is incorrect. The way you have it now a booking can only have one seat, but your requirement says you need to be able to choose multiple. What you need is a **many-to-many** relationship. Ask google to find out what that means.

Here's what I think should work:

- Customer: id, name
- Ticket: ticket_id, time
- Booking: id, customer_id, ticket_id
- Seat: id, status, price
- seat_ticket_map: seat_id, ticket_id

So to attach new seats to a ticket you make a new seat_to_ticket_map instance.

I wasn't sure where to put price but I think it makes sense on Seat. It depends on your requirements though

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's more clear now about assigning more seats to a ticket. I understand that a ticket can have multiple seats, but one seat can also be asigned to multiple tickets? I think I confuse the role of ticket. I thought the ticket was unique for every customer, but it isn't? I see it has a time property, so that means the same ticket with id=1, can be sold to many customers and that means that the booking table will have many records with ticket_id=1, but with a different customer_id every time, right? So, the ticket is like a "product" in a typical shopping cart?

Comment: And what about the capacity? Where should I define this?

Comment: You need to look at your requirements, I don't know them. Ask the people who you are writing this thing for. I find what helps is to first draw a picture of what the database should represent as a sort of block diagram. Yes, the mapping table allows you to assign one seat to multiple tickets, you just need to use logic to make sure nothing impossible gets assigned.